# Laravel Relation where not in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I have following table

**users**

```
id | username | password

1 | scott | 98746
2 | mark | 6542
3 | michel | 6589
```

**user_detail**

```
id | user_id | status | mobile_number 

1 | 1 | pending | 987643210

2 | 2 | review | 3216547901
```

Now i want to retrieve those record where user has no records in `user_detail` table where `status=pending`

I have tried using relations in latest version

```
$user=User::with('userDetail')

        ->whereDoesntHave('userDetail',function ($query){

             $query->where('status','pending');
        })->get();
```

Same logic i am looking for without relations in laravel.Since we are using old laravel version which doesn't support.

Comment: How do you check a user_detail field if you do not want the user to have user_detail records? It does not make sense.

Comment: @MEDZ.yes since it has many logics ,so to keep simple i posted small version

Comment: Show `userDetail` relation code.

Comment: @Styx. Martin Dimitrov already gave answer its perfectly working but i am looking for eloquent way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you mean by there are no relations, but if you have to do it with plain SQL, the query will look something like this:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id not in (SELECT u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN user_details d ON (u.id = d.user_id AND d.status = 'pending'));"
```

Then you can run the query by calling:

```
$results = DB::select($qry);
```

PS: Since I was not able to find it in the old docs, `DB::select()` may require 2nd param. If that is the case, just pass `null` as the second parameter.

**EDIT:**
I am not sure if this will work, and since it is for an old version, I am unable to test it, but something similar should work:

```
$rest = User::whereNotIn('id', function($q){
    $q->select('user_id')->from('user_detail')->where('status','pending');
});
```

Comment: @Martin.do you know how i can achieve this using eloquent

Comment: @vision Try the edit. Please note, that even if this works, there might be and probably is a better way to do this. The first way should work better tbh.

Comment: @Martin.Thatway i have already tried ,any way ,thanks for the effort

Comment: What is not working in that way? Is there some error or?

Comment: no error but looking for can it be possbile in single query like we write in raw query

Comment: @vision Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202275/discussion-between-martin-dimitrov-and-vision).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this by using left joins, something like this:

```
$rest = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('userDetail','users.id','=','userDetail.user_id')
        ->whereNull('userDetail.id')
        ->orWhere('userDetail.status','=','pending')
        ->get();
```

If you need the eloquent collection of Users, you can use the `hydrate` method like this:

```
$rest = User::hydrate(DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('userDetail','users.id','=','userDetail.user_id')
        ->whereNull('userDetail.id')
        ->orWhere('userDetail.status','=','pending')
        ->select('users.*')
        ->get()->toArray());
```

cheers!

Comment: @leopinzon.Thank you